# Weird bug in my website concerning title

Tags: html, css

I have released my personal website but there seems to be a weird bug for phone users. When I verify the website in a "inspect element" on my PC. Everything seems fine, but on my iPhone, it's a different story.

The "i do cool things with computers" seems to cut the "s" off and it's very annoying. I tried de-bugging but nothing works.

Also, in the "Contact Me" section in the bottom, the picture in the background is extremely zoomed in for no reason?

[GitHub Full Code](https://github.com/mohanadarafe/My-Personal-Website)

[My Website](http://www.mohanadarafe.io)

[What happens](https://gyazo.com/42e014214e859e89e665c51933c4b1d4)

[Zoomed in background?](https://gyazo.com/878854e80a0297547f5586f8fd795f8e)

HTML:

```
<p class="line-1 anim-typewriter">hi, i'm mohanad</p>
<p class="line-2 anim-typewriter2">i do cool things with computers</p>
```

CSS:

```
.line-2{
font-family: monospace;
position: relative;
top: 30%;
left: 15%;
width: 25em;
margin: 0 auto;
font-size: 250%;
text-align: left;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.anim-typewriter2{
 animation: typewriter2 2s steps(44) 1s 1 normal both,
     blinkTextCursor2 500ms steps(44) infinite normal;
     animation-delay: 3.5s;
 }
 @keyframes typewriter2 {
 from {
 width: 0;
 }

 to {
 width: 21em;
 }
 }
 @keyframes blinkTextCursor2 {
 from {
  border-right-color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
  }
  to {
  border-right-color: transparent;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question

Comment: Make a reproduceable code sample, put it in your question, along with any relevant screen shots.

Comment: @SmokeyDawson sorry, just did

Comment: Its because you are using `width: 25em` on your .line-2 make it larger on mobile and the s wont be cut off, try `width: 26 or 27em`

Comment: @SmokeyDawson i tried but nothing changes

Comment: @moe try using a px width

Comment: @SmokeyDawson thing is i deleted the entire .line-2 attributes for testing purposes and nothing changed?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think the issue is not with line "i do cool things with computers" ..
Your HTML structure is not covering the whole page, this is because of the following styles

```
.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Change the container width to 100% to make it work across responsive views.
Additionally, change your  HTML to :

```
<header id="home">
          <nav class="">
             <div class="menu-icon lightSpeedIn animated">
                <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
              </div>
               <div class="logo fadeIn animated">MOHANAD ARAFE</div>
               <div class="menu lightSpeedIn animated" data-wow-delay="1s">
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
              </div>
          </nav>
<div class="container">
          <p class="line-1 anim-typewriter">hi, i'm mohanad</p>
          <p class="line-2 anim-typewriter2">i do cool things with computers</p>
          <div class="readMore wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="5.7s" style="visibility: visible; animation-delay: 5.7s; animation-name: fadeIn;">
            <a href="#aboutme"><h3>Read More</h3></a>
            <img src="./img/arrowDown.png" alt="Arrow Down">
          </div>
          <div class="location">griffith observatory, ca</div>
</div>
      </header>
```

Please try these changes and it may change some original styles of yours. We can fix them in next version.

Contact HTML:

```
    <section id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <center>
    <h1>LET'S BUILD TOGETHER</h1>
    <p>If you need a website or any designs, feel free to contact me so we can design together! Also, if you see any bugs
      in the website, please let me know so I can fix it. Otherwise, if you just want to talk, shoot me an email!
      <form class="contact-form" action="contact.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required><br>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required><br>
        <input type="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required><br>
        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Message" required></textarea><br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="form-control submit">SEND MESSAGE</button>
      </form>
    </center>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#contact{
background: url('../img/contactBg.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position:left;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: works now! what about the "contact me" background img?

Comment: Please provide a new version of website along with above changes. Will be easier to help

Comment: Well, if your question is solved, would appreciate if you could accept the answer

Comment: well This is happening because you are using "background-size : cover " which actually " Resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges". Other options available to set background-size are "https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp". Please see what suits best to your requirement.

Comment: Is your background size issue is solved?